"A purple bander copy"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 19)

(in the classroom; Mr Shrubs, the teacher; William and Martin, choristers at King's College, Cambridge)


It took a few weeks for William to get used to arriving late for the first lesson of the day, but now he quite enjoys walking in once everyone has started and having a quiet few moments with the teacher to catch them up. As they weave through the desks in the room of bent heads, Martin mutters, 'I'm going to learn it (the Welsh song 'Myfanwy') in English, and I'll sing it for my party piece at Christmas.'
Mr Shrubs comes to their desks and drops a worksheet before them. He crouches down, resting his big index finger on William's purple bander copy. 'Long divisions. More practice carrying on from yesterday.'
William can do long division. . . .

I take "purple bander copy" to mean a copy bordered by a printed purple streak around the paper/copy. It seems to a bit emphasise the privileged status of this college. "bander" seems to be a French loan word? Is it pronounced in French?

I can find no French meaning that would make it a likely loanword in this (or any other) context.

See Purple Band Guided Reading Questions

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/bander

@FumbleFingers when the book in question was written, the coloured reading-book-band scheme existed (though it's not relevant to maths, and anyway "bander" would have to be a typo for "banded").  When the book is set, it didn't.

My guess is that it's a (purple) (bander copy) - or Banda copy, Banda being one of the common brands of spirit duplicators, which typically used purple-coloured wax.
"Banda" was somewhat genericized in the UK, but I can't find any references as to "bander" replacing "Banda" as a term for those machines. Perhaps this was local to some area, or the author has only heard the word and has not seen it written.

I belong to the generation that can remember school documents produced on a duplicator. I don't remember ever hearing the term 'Banda', but apparently it was used as a generic name for the machines (cf 'hoover').

@KateBunting "Banda" was, from my research, but "bander" wasn't - all I could find were a few posts on the Internet, and most of them were people with school memories of those who probably haven't seen the word written either.

(I'm a bit young for duplicators, but I remember that carbon copy paper back in my school days was often purple).

The wet-ink duplicators were called mimeograph machines in the US. The purple ink contained methanol and isopropanol.  Kids used to hold the mimeographed pages to their noses and take a deep breath.

At my infants school, I was chosen to help Mrs Taylor work 'the Banda'. It had that maker's name in big letters on the side. @TimR -when I was older pupils said you could get high by sniffing a newly printed page, but it never worked for me. As a teenager I got to help with a Gestetner and a Roneo, other brands of duplicating machines. The error reminds me of the  time I saw 'vesper' for 'Vespa' in a British novel.

@MichaelHarvey  Luck-y.  I got to assist with clean up of a classmate's vomit using the ready can of vomit absorbent ("pour it on, soak it up, sweep it out"). We had to add a fourth step, mop up after. There was always the risk of a vomit chain-reaction.

@TimR - At the school with the Banda, there was a lady called Mrs Lane, not a teacher, who came if someone had 'been sick' as we say in Britain. If a kid wet themselves they were sent along to her room. At the age of five that was not unheard of.

@TimR I think mimeographs work a little differently from Banda/Ditto machines - using dedicated stencils and colored ink rather than impressing wax from a carbon copy-like sheet on the back side of the paper and using a clear solvent to dissolve pigment. The results do seem pretty similar though, so I wouldn't be surprised if the distinction was often not made.

@MaciejStachowski  Banda/Ditto machines -- those names were generally unknown in the States. The average Joe wasn't even aware there was a different way of doing it.

@KateBunting we had such machines in junior school (mid/late 80s); they sometimes made it to the classroom. I don't recall ever seeing the name written down, so whether they were "Banda" or "bander" was immaterial.  We had a range of colours, and occasionally used more than one pass with different colours.

Maybe the author knew Banda, but someone in the editorial process didn't

@TimR - I am told by my American sister-in-law, who is over visiting, that the best-known spirit duplicator manufacturer in the United States was Ditto Corporation of Chicago. She worked for them briefly before college packing typewriter ribbons.

@ChrisH - Banda was B and A from Block and Anderson

@MichaelHarvey interesting, but if you never saw it written down, not obvious

@MichaelHarvey Maybe Ditto was used more in business? I only know these machines from elementary school, where everyone called them mimeographs. I don't recall seeing the "Ditto" name.https://www.chattanoogan.com/2006/7/27/89955/Remembering-the-Ditto-and-Mimeograph.aspx

@ChrisH - indeed (i.e. not obvious). 'Banda' was 'written down' on the side of every machine, it chromium-plated letters. I never knew how the name (Banda) came about before about 5 minutes ago. My researches also threw up a name I had forgotten about, a company called A B Dick, based in Chicago, but who sold table top duplicators all over the world. Now there's a name for schoolboys to remember.

@MichaelHarvey maybe "not recalled" in my case as I did handle such a machine (It was 35-37 years ago after all).  Or maybe it was missing the badge, or an imitation.
